# how to use an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to do a little work in JavaScript and am new to the language, but not to program languages.

```
class Key{
    constructor(nm, keydata)    {
        var name = nm;
        var data = keydata;
    }
}

var KeySet = [];
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    KeySet.push(new Key("item " +   i, "some data for " + i));
}

for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    console.log(i,KeySet[i].name," ->",KeySet[i].data)
}
```

I am getting this at the console:

> ```
> 0 undefined -> undefined 
> 1 undefined -> undefined 
> 2 undefined -> undefined 
> 3 undefined -> undefined 
> 4 undefined -> undefined
> ```

1. Can I even build an array of objects?
2. If so, what is wrong with the above? What is the best way?
3. Do I have to do anything like cast the array item contents to a Key object to use it? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there! The result is `undefined` because the constructor declares the variables in its local scope, instead of defining those variables as instance variables.

To define instance variables, you need to bind those using `this` keyword. See the working example below:

```js
class Key {
  constructor(nm, keydata) {
    this.name = nm;
    this.data = keydata;
  }
}

var KeySet = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  KeySet.push(new Key("item " + i, "some data for " + i));
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i, KeySet[i].name, " ->", KeySet[i].data)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it almost always a head slapper?  I am having issues with not having to declare every variable specifically.

Comment: By the way, do you have a favorite comprehensive source on the language?

Comment: @JohnHard -- for the second comment, I suggest you to regularly read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), and refer to its documentation for any help.